# Logstash Kafka - Error: negative length -62 given

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, avro, elastic-stack

I am facing the similar issue to this article: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/argumenterror-when-using-kafka-input-avro-codec/116975

Logstash Conf:

```
input {
    kafka{
        group_id => "group_1"
        topics => ["topic_1"]
        bootstrap_servers => "192.168.0.1:9092"
        codec => avro {
            schema_uri => "/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/CONFIG_HOME/myschema.avsc"
        }
    }
}

output{
    stdout{

    }
}
```

Error Logs:

```
[2018-01-25T11:54:37,060][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! 
{:error=>#<ArgumentError: negative length -15 given>, :backtrace=>[
"org/jruby/ext/stringio/StringIO.java:788:in `read'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:106:in `read'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:93:in `read_bytes'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:99:in `read_string'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:299:in `read_data'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:384:in `block in read_record'", 
"org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:382:in `read_record'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:310:in `read_data'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:275:in `read'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-codec-avro-3.2.3-java/lib/logstash/codecs/avro.rb:77:in `decode'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-kafka-8.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/kafka.rb:254:in `block in thread_runner'", 
"/files/GA6/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-kafka-8.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/kafka.rb:253:in `block in thread_runner'"
]}
```

Schema Sample:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Sample",
    "doc": "Sample Schema",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
        }, {
            "name": "address",
            "type": "string"
        }, {
            "name": "salary",
            "type": "long"
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on some discussion, I have also added the following:

```
key_deserializer_class => "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer"
value_deserializer_class => "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer"
```

But still the issue persist...

Let me know if you require any further information.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue @Smit ? I am also looking for the same

Comment: Yes @JinnaBalu, Just upgrade the logstash to the latest version it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Still i am facing the same issue with 7.10.2 `negative length -1 given`

Comment: Are you using coec?

Comment: Yes, here is my config `kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "192.0.2.1:19092"
    topics => ["newsfeed_topic"]
    group_id => "ds_newsfeed_topic"
    client_id => "ds_newsfeed_topic_client"
    auto_offset_reset => 'earliest'
    decorate_events => true
    codec => avro {
        schema_uri => "/usr/share/logstash/avsc/news_storage.avsc"
    }
    tags => ["newsfeed"]
  }`

Comment: you do not need codec anymore

Comment: you can simply put schema_url (this is scheam registery url) and it will take care of the avro conversion

Comment: I am getting this error now `[logstash.inputs.kafka    ] Unknown setting 'schema_url' for kafka`

Comment: hmm... Okay I will try look for references.

Comment: oh it needs to be `schema_registry_url` please find the issue here:https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-kafka/pull/239

Comment: @JinnaBalu added answer (summarising the chat above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually raised to the Logstash team and was finally integrated into Logstash Kafka input itself rather then codec:

Usage:

```
input {
  kafka {
    id => "kafka_avro_events"
    group_id => "logstash_kafka_avro"
    topics_pattern => "some_avro_topic"
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka:9092"
    decorate_events => true
    value_deserializer_class => "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer"
    schema_registry_url => "http://schemaregistry:8081"
    metadata_max_age_ms => "5000"
    codec => "json"
  }
}
```

Please ensure you are using v > 7.10.x

Github Issue: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-kafka/pull/239